# Leather furniture storage - is unheated ok for short term?

Tags: furniture

Sometimes for work I need to leave leather furniture in an unheated unit for 2-3 days. Temperature at night is around 5c degrees (3-10 range) with moderate humidity.

I read somewhere that leaving leather in the cold damages and dries it out although it talked about more below freezing temperature. Since some of the furniture I handle is expensive I am concerned how much I should be worried about it.

At this temperature will there be any damage? We are talking over weeks right aka 2-3 days won't be a problem?

Thank you

Comment: Think about tack and saddles in a stable...

Comment: True true, wondering if thick tough leather would react differently than stuff they use for delicate fine furniture though.

Comment: Fair enough (although they don't use just delicate leather for fine furniture, the Eames lounge chair and ottoman and the Le Corbusier sling chair spring to mind). I knew I should have added this: or leather furniture in unheated rooms in British country houses during our long, dreary winters. Leather definitely degrades if it gets damper and less damp in successive cycles over a long *without maintenance*; but with maintenance it can withstand those same conditions over the same timeframe.

Comment: Got it thank you. That's what I was suspecting we are talking about longer cycles of changing humidity and temperature. Not a few days.